# enable scripting in elasticsearch 2.2.1

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch-2.2.1 wont start when I add the line

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

to my elasticsearch.yml file as show [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-scripting.html)

What is could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check instruction for [appropriate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/modules-scripting.html) version. Link you provided for version 1.6

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
```