# Update with scripting in Elastisearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, scripting

I am trying to use scripting in Elasticsearch to update some data. My script is the following:

```
    for i in df.index:
        es.update(
            index=indexout,
            doc_type="suggestedTag",
            id=df['dataId'][i],
            _source=True,
            body={
                "script": {
                    "inline": "ctx._source.items.suggestionTime = updated_time",
                    "params": {
                        "updated_time": {
                            "field": df['suggestionTime'][i]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )
```

But when I do that I get the following error:

> raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code,error_message, additional_info) elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', '[jLIZdmn][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]')

And I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438320/enable-scripting-in-elasticsearch-2-2-1) to enable it, but even with this and [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/modules-scripting-security.html) it still raises the same error. I inserted the following elements in the config/elasticsearch.yml file :

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
script.update: true
```

But I still cannot avoid the RequestError that I have since the beginning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, just need to add `params.` before `updated_time`:

```
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.items.suggestionTime = params.updated_time",
    "params": {
      "updated_time": {
        "field": df['suggestionTime'][i]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you would try to run your query in [Kibana console](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.5/console-kibana.html), it would look something like this:

```
POST /my-index-2018-12/doc/AWdpylbN3HZjlM-Ibd7X/_update
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.suggestionTime = updated_time",
    "params": {
      "updated_time": {
        "field": "2018-10-03T18:33:00Z"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You would see the entire response of the Elasticsearch, that would look like your error message + valuable details:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[7JNqOhT][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "failed to execute script",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "script_exception",
      "reason": "compile error",
      "script_stack": [
        "... _source.suggestionTime = updated_time",
        "                             ^---- HERE"
      ],
      "script": "ctx._source.suggestionTime = updated_time",
      "lang": "painless",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Variable [updated_time] is not defined."
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Which points us to the syntax error (parameters, apparently, [are injected as `params` object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates)).

I believe the scripting settings are not the source of the problem in this case.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This worked, thank you very much ! I edited the title in order to reflect the issue I was actually having instead of the one I thought I had.